# Cummulative sum by year_month, location, state in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, select, hive, sum, window-functions

I want to make a cumulative count using Hive SQL in `recorrencia` column according to the other ones.

```
 +------------+---------+-------+--------------+--+
| t.ano_mes  | t.site  | t.uf  | recorrencia  |
+------------+---------+-------+--------------+--+
| 202001     | 174     | AM    | 1            |
| 202002     | 174     | AM    | 1            |
| 202003     | 174     | AM    | 1            |
| 202004     | 174     | AM    | 1            |
| 202005     | 174     | AM    | 1            |
| 202006     | 174     | AM    | 1            |
| 202007     | 174     | AM    | 1            |
| 202008     | 174     | AM    | 1            |
| 202005     | 1JN     | SP    | 1            |
| 202006     | 1JN     | SP    | 1            |
| 202005     | 1LJ     | SP    | 1            |
| 202009     | 1LJ     | SP    | 1            |
| 202001     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |
| 202002     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |
| 202003     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |
| 202004     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |
| 202005     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |
| 202006     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |
| 202007     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |
```

**Desired output**

```
+------------+---------+-------+--------------+--------+
| t.ano_mes  | t.site  | t.uf  | recorrencia  |cum_rec
+------------+---------+-------+--------------+--------+
| 202001     | 174     | AM    | 1            |1
| 202002     | 174     | AM    | 1            |2
| 202003     | 174     | AM    | 1            |3
| 202004     | 174     | AM    | 1            |4
| 202005     | 174     | AM    | 1            |5
| 202006     | 174     | AM    | 1            |6
| 202007     | 174     | AM    | 1            |7
| 202008     | 174     | AM    | 1            |8
| 202005     | 1JN     | SP    | 1            |1
| 202006     | 1JN     | SP    | 1            |2
| 202005     | 1LJ     | SP    | 1            |1
| 202009     | 1LJ     | SP    | 1            |2
| 202001     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |1
| 202002     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |2
| 202003     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |3
| 202004     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |4
| 202005     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |5
| 202006     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |6
| 202007     | 1RG     | SP    | 1            |7
```

I've tried a lot of functions like `COUNT(*) OVER (t.ano_mes)` and `COUNT(*) OVER (t.site)` but it runs the sum until the end of table, and do not restarts as the `t.site` changes.

As soon as `t.site` changes, the counter should restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be:

```
sum(recorrencia) over(partition by t.site order by t.ano_mes) as cum_rec
```

The `partition by` clause causes the sum to reset every time the site changes.

Note that if `recorrencia` is always `1`, as shown in your sample data, then `row_number()` is sufficient:

```
row_number() over(partition by t.site order by t.ano_mes) as cum_rec
```

Comment: i think you mean to say 'Note that if recorrencia is `not` always 1, ... '

Comment: Thanks. It did help me a lot!